# Remove copyright in Xcode generated source code

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there any way to completely remove the comment with the copyright notice when creating a new source code file with Xcode 4?

Insted of:

```
//
//  MainView.h
//  ProjectName
//
//  Created by First Last Name on 1/2/34.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Company Name. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainView : UIView

@end
```

I'd like to have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainView : UIView

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to do what you want is to create a custom file template. Make a copy of Apple's file template, open the header file, and remove the introductory comments. More detailed information on creating custom file templates is in the following article:

[Creating Custom Xcode 4 File Templates](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/11/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/)

Comment: You can modify the templates. The problem is your modifications would get overwritten the next time you update Xcode to a newer version. Creating a custom template allows your changes to survive Xcode updates.